# How can i echo the newline after everyline

Tags: linux, bash

My host is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4` with bash.
When i use this command: `netstat -tnpl | grep "tcp" | awk '{print $4}'`,than it output the following:

```
127.0.0.1:2208
0.0.0.0:871
0.0.0.0:9001
0.0.0.0:3306
0.0.0.0:111
127.0.0.1:631
127.0.0.1:25
127.0.0.1:6010
127.0.0.1:6011
127.0.0.1:2207
:::80
:::22
:::8601
::1:6010
::1:6011
:::443
```

But when use this: `` ip_port=`netstat -tnpl | grep "tcp" | awk '{print $4}'` && echo $ip_port ``,it becomes the following:

```
127.0.0.1:2208 0.0.0.0:871 0.0.0.0:9001 0.0.0.0:3306 0.0.0.0:111 127.0.0.1:631 127.0.0.1:25 127.0.0.1:6010 127.0.0.1:6011 127.0.0.1:2207 :::80 :::22 :::8601 ::1:6010 ::1:6011 :::443
```

It becomes online. How did this happen and what i want is the original format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose your variable in quotes when echoing:

```
echo "$ip_port"
```

Also, you don't need to use both `grep` and `awk` because `awk` can `grep`. You can simplify your command to:

```
netstat -tnpl | awk '/tcp/{print $4}'
```

Comment: Thank you~ But did you know why i miss the double quote it comes with that result?

Comment: It's due to [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting). Double quoting suppresses word splitting.